# Users outside domain administrators group lost access to outlook and shared folders

Tags: dns, outlook, directory, exchange-server, administrator

At some point over the weekend most users lost access to Outlook (they were unable to sync) and to some shared folders. The users that kept their workstations logged in during that time still had access to both Outlook and the shared folders.

If added to a "domain administrators" group, the users have access to both Outlook and the shared folders. Obviously this is not a solution, even in the short term, but it is a symptom of the problem.

I don't think someone deliberately changed a setting in the server. I do believe this to be a wrong setting somewhere. We currently have a Windows 2003 SBS as an Exchange server, domain controller and primary DNS.

We've been having issues with the DNS servers. Sometimes we need to add a shared folder by ip. Other times it is added by `name.domain.local`, and sometimes by just their name. Although I think the current problem is not related, I mention this for context.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research i found it to be an issue with the CAL´s, the licenses somehow reset to default values and that was preventing users from accessing outlook and share folders.
After stopping "license logging" service, using the info contained in autolicstr.cpa and passing it to licstr.cpa, then restarting the service...the licences were restored and everyone had access again.